# GCP API - Getting Max retries exceeded error while making API call - /oauth2/v4/token

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform

While making call to the GCP API - https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token, from Python client, getting below error intermittently. And once we get this error need to wait for more than 24 hrs to make a successful call.

Error while getting GCP Token: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /oauth2/v4/token

How to get rid-off this issue?

Thanks,
rmp

Comment: It's expected behavior. You've used all you quota, so to solve this issue you should request an increase in quota. Have a look at the [documentation](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9028764?hl=en). Does it answer your question?

Comment: 1) Do not call that endpoint so frequently. 2) Your question includes no code or other details to offer suggestions for improvements. 3) Tokens are valid for typically one hour. Cache the token and expiration time. Reissue as required. 4) If the code is running on a compute service, use the metadata service.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza - Let us try increasing the limit. Thanks for your response

Comment: @JohnHanley Will try increasing the limit and see how does it behave

Comment: I do not believe you can increase the quota for the authorization endpoint. Solving the problem is the correct approach, increasing the quota is a band-aid covering up a bad design.